What insect is this in photo? 1.5" size
What insect is this in photo? Saw this in outdoor table and wonder if it can bite and if it has venom. The size is about 1.5 inches and located in the Philippines.


You need to edit the question to give the regional location and approximate size of the insect.

Could be a longhorn beetle of some sort. Would need photos from other angles to get a more firm ID.

The other photo is so blurred. Its on the foot of table besides a swimming pool at condo. Good to know it is not dangerous so we can sit at the table again tnx

I would say this is some Hemiptera
